# Graph Search in C++17

Tags: c++, graph, c++17

**Overview**

I am constructing a Graph with randomly generated nodes called `Position`s.
The Graph has a width and a height and is represented using an adjacency list `std::map<std::pair<int, int>, mrrobo::Position> m_maze;`, that are open, closed, and may not have a route back to the root. I want to find a single path to the Position with an x value of width - 1 of and y value of height - 1, the end of the maze. If not possible I return an empty array. Also, the generation of the maze Positions is handled by a function managed by another developer namespace called `bool otherns::generate_postion(int x, int y)` so that's abstracted and given to my code in an assumed valid state.

The primary feedback I'm looking for is with my implementation of graph search in `Graph::search()`. As well as how I determine `possible_edge = { {x, y-1}, {x-1, y}, {x+1, y}, {x, y+1} }` in my `Graph::get_position_edges()` function. Using C++17 features I want to find ways to optimize this graph search if possible.

**Main.cpp**

```
#include <iostream>

#include "graph.cpp"

int main()
{
    mrrobo::Graph graph;
    std::cout << "width: " << graph.width() << '\n';
    std::cout << "height: " << graph.height() << '\n';

    graph.get_position_edges();
    graph.search();

    return 0;
}
```

**Graph.h**

```
#ifndef GRAPH_H
#define GRAPH_H

#include <cstring>
#include <iostream>
#include <iterator>
#include <queue>
#include <stack>
#include <string>
#include <utility>
#include <vector>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string>
#include <sstream>
#include <map>

namespace mrrobo
{
    struct Position
    {
        int x;
        int y;
        bool is_open;
        bool is_visited;
        std::vector<Position> edges;
    };
    class Graph
    {
        private:
            int m_height;
            int m_width;
        public:
            Graph();
            std::map<std::pair<int, int>, mrrobo::Position> m_graph;
            int width();
            int height();
            void get_position_edges();
            void search();
    };
}

#endif /* GRAPH_H */
```

**Graph.cpp**

```
#include "graph.h"

mrrobo::Graph::Graph() {
    otherns::set_width_and_height();
}

int mrrobo::Graph::width() { return m_width; }
int mrrobo::Graph::height() { return m_height; }

void mrrobo::Graph::get_position_edges() {
    std::ostringstream oss;

    std::vector<std::pair<int, int>> open_postions;
    mrrobo::Position p;
    p.is_visited = false;
    for (int y = 0; y < m_height; ++y) {
        for (int x = 0; x < m_width; ++x) {
            bool result = otherns::generate_postion(x,y);
            if(result) {
                p.is_open = true;
                m_graph.insert( {{x,y}, p} );
                open_postions.push_back({x,y});
                oss << "○ ";
            } else {
                p.is_open = false;
                m_graph.insert( {{x,y}, p} );
                oss << "● ";
            }
        }
        oss << '\n';
    }
    std::cout << '\n' << oss.str() << '\n';

    for(int n=0; n < open_postions.size(); ++n) {
        int x = open_postions[n].first;
        int y = open_postions[n].second;
        std::vector<std::pair<int, int>> possible_edge = { {x, y-1}, {x-1, y}, {x+1, y}, {x, y+1} };
        for(int i=0; i < possible_edge.size(); ++i) {
            int x_edge = possible_edge[i].first;
            int y_edge = possible_edge[i].second;

            if((x_edge > -1 && x_edge < m_width + 1) &&
                (y_edge > -1 && y_edge < m_height + 1) &&
                m_graph[{x_edge, y_edge}].is_open) {

                    m_graph[{x,y}].edges.push_back( {x_edge, y_edge} );
            }
        }
    }
}

void mrrobo::Graph::search() {
    std::stack<std::pair<int,int>> reversed_path;
    int x = 0;
    int y = 0;
    bool dead_end = true;

    if(m_graph[{x,y}].is_open) {
        reversed_path.push({x,y});
        while((x < m_width || y < m_height) && !reversed_path.empty()) {
            if(x == m_width - 1 && y == m_height - 1) {
                m_graph[{x,y}].is_visited = true;
                reversed_path.push({x,y});
                break;
            }
            dead_end = true;
            for(auto edge : m_graph[{x,y}].edges) {
                if(m_graph[{edge.x,edge.y}].is_open && m_graph[{edge.x,edge.y}].is_visited == false) {
                    m_graph[{x,y}].is_visited = true;
                    reversed_path.push({x,y});
                    x = edge.x;
                    y = edge.y;
                    dead_end = false;
                    break;
                }
            }
            if(dead_end) {
                m_graph[{x,y}].is_visited = true;
                x = reversed_path.top().first;
                y = reversed_path.top().second;
                reversed_path.pop();
            }
        }
    }

    std::stringstream solution_stream;
    if(reversed_path.empty()) {
        solution_stream << "[]";
    }
    else {
        std::stack<std::pair<int,int>> path;
        while(reversed_path.empty() == false) {
            path.push(reversed_path.top());
            reversed_path.pop();
        }
        solution_stream << '[';
        path.pop();
        while(path.empty() ==  false) {
            x = path.top().first;
            y = path.top().second;
            if(x != m_width - 1 || y != m_width - 1) {
                solution_stream << "{\"x\": " << x << ", \"y\": " << y << "}, ";
            } else {
                solution_stream << "{\"x\": " << x << ", \"y\": " << y << "}";
            }
            path.pop();
        }
        solution_stream << ']';
    }

    std::cout << solution_stream.str() << '\n';
}
```

**Sample output**

```
width: 6
height: 6

○ ○ ● ○ ○ ○
○ ● ○ ● ● ○
○ ● ○ ● ● ●
○ ○ ○ ○ ○ ○
● ● ● ● ● ○
○ ○ ○ ○ ○ ○

[{"x": 0, "y": 0}, {"x": 0, "y": 1}, {"x": 0, "y": 2}, {"x": 0, "y": 3}, {"x": 1, "y": 3}, {"x": 2, "y": 3}, {"x": 3, "y": 3}, {"x": 4, "y": 3}, {"x": 5, "y": 3}, {"x": 5, "y": 4}, {"x": 5, "y": 5}]
```

Comment: `mrrobo::Garph graph;` Does this really work?

Comment: Yes is there a syntax error here?

Comment: No, just a typo: `Garph`.

Comment: Fixed it, must have been a copy paste error when formatting the code